# ¿Significan lo mismo "Hubiéramos podido..." y "Podríamos haber..."?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, condicional

¿Existe alguna diferencia de significado o uso entre las siguientes estructuras?

- Hubiéramos podido hablar por teléfono
- Podríamos haber hablado por teléfono

Comment: "Hubiéramos podido" = "we ought to have been able to."  "Podríamos haber hablado por teléfono" = "we could have called."

Comment: That’s how I interpreted the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: "have been able to" and "could have" so, same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad, la primera debería ser: *habríamos podido hablar por teléfono*, entregando así el resultado de la situación imaginaria del pasado.

Entonces, ¿hay diferencia? Pues sí.

1. *Habríamos podido hablar por teléfono* implica que la situación no ocurrió en el pasado.

   > *Habríamos podido hablar por teléfono si no se hubiese ido la señal.* (= como la señal se fue, entonces no hablamos por teléfono)
2. *Podríamos haber hablado por teléfono* implica que la situación no ocurrió en el pasado porque se prefirió otra opción de acción.

   > *Podríamos haber hablado por teléfono si hubieses tenido tu celular.* (= pero no lo trajiste, así que nos juntamos a hablar en persona)

Cabe destacar que en distintas partes se acostumbra a ocupar *hubiese/hubiera* (como en el primer ejemplo) en ambas cláusulas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias profe por esta respuesta clara, contungente y bien estructurada. Le deseo un feliz día.

Comment: @nic de profe no tengo nada, pero me gusta ayudar. :)

Comment: "profe" casi de acuerdo. Para mi ambas _habríamos_ o _hubiéramos_ pueden usarse. En la conjuración que tiene la RAE aparece hubiéramos como Pretérito imperfecto/Pretérito y aparece habríamos como Condicional simple/Pospretérito. De hecho yo prefiero _hubiéramos_ sobre _habríamos_

Comment: @DGaleano me suena horrible! Preferencias regionales, ya sabes. 

Answer (score 0):

**No es cierto**, ambas opciones significan lo mismo, **sin diferencia alguna**. La respuesta dada más arriba está estructurada y bien explicada, pero no se sustenta en la realidad. Si la persona que respondió así encuentra que ambas opciones tienen esa diferencia de significado, es una sensación suya personal pero no corresponde al significado real de las dos alternativas.

Comment: Es tu opinion, si tienes alguna referencia tu respuesta ganara mucho.